# Why does this code loop 16 times?

Tags: assembly, x86

How many times the again loop will be repeated?

```
mov bx,0 
mov cx,0 
again: 
shr cx,1 
inc bx 
loop again
```

The answer is 16, but why?

and when we have `shl` insted of `shr` the answer is: infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Just run the code in your head. The only odd thing here (if it's even odd) is that `loop` decrements `cx` and branches based on the result.

Answer (score 4):

There are two fundamental ways of understanding a problem like this:

1. Think through and "execute" the code in your head. Consider what each instruction means, and how it will affect the flow of the code.
2. Type the code into an editor, assemble it, and run it under a debugger. Use the debugger to single-step through the code, watching the values of registers and its overall behavior.

Note that these are basically the same thing; one just has the machine do all the work, you just watch the magic happen. If you're relatively comfortable with assembly language, approach #1 will be all you need in simple cases like this one. If you're just learning and don't quite have the feel for it in your bones, then it can be very useful to "cheat" and get the debugger to help out.

Since there's no debugger available on Stack Overflow (although I still encourage you to try this for yourself), let's resort to the manual method using our brains:

> ```
> mov bx,0 
> mov cx,0
> ```

Obviously, this starts out initializing the `bx` and `cx` registers to 0.

Note that no real assembly programmer would ever write the code like this. They would always write

```
xor bx, bx
xor cx, cx
```

This has the same effect (any number XOR itself is 0), but it is faster and uses fewer bytes of code.

Inside of the loop, this code runs:

> ```
> shr cx,1 
> inc bx
> ```

`SHR` shifts the destination operand (in this case, `cx`) right by the source operand (in this case, a constant `1`). Recall that a right-shift is equivalent to a division by 2, but faster. So this is the same as `cx = cx >> 1`, or `cx = cx / 2`.

`INC` increments its operand by 1. It is the same as `bx = bx + 1`.

> ```
> loop again
> ```

The `LOOP` instruction is not widely used anymore in x86 assembly programming because it is relatively slow. About the only time you'd use it was if small code was more important than fast code. As such, I have to look up what it does. You can find this information by Googling a mnemonic name and "x86", or you can find it one of Intel's manuals, or you can find it in the material in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, or you can find it in whatever textbook/course materials you are using to learn assembly-language programming. I looked it up [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_161.html), which is a site that includes an online transcription of Intel's manual, found using Google.

Turns out, the `LOOP` instruction decrements the count register (`cx`), and does another iteration of the loop if the `cx != 0`. Otherwise, if `cx == 0`, it stops looping and falls through.

Armed with that knowledge, then, you should be able to "execute" the code in your head. What's happening to `bx` is quite irrelevant. The only interesting operations are those that are affecting `cx`. What makes it interesting is that, since `cx` starts out at 0, and `0 >> 1` is 0, the `LOOP` instruction *decrements* it by 1, making it -1 after the first iteration of the loop.

It is a bit unusual (often a bug) to use bitwise right-shift on signed values, but it is a well-defined operation in x86 assembly (unlike in C or C++). What happens, basically, is that the shifted-off bits (in this case, the last bit) disappear and the empty bit slots are filled with zeros. So, a right-shift by 1 would just place a 0 in the most-significant bit. (And, technically, it would place that shifted-off bit in the carry flag, but that doesn't matter in this code because nothing is testing the carry flag.)

For example, `6 >> 1 == 3`    (`0000 0110 >> 1 == 0000 0011`).

---

Now, you should understand the behavior well enough to be able to answer the second, follow-up question. But if you need a hint, [look up the behavior of the `SHL` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html). It is a bitwise left-shift, equivalent to a multiplication by 2.

The code is going to loop infinitely in this case because `cx` will never be 0, which is the condition that the `LOOP` instruction is checking for! Why is this so? Because `LOOP` *first* decrements `cx`, and *then* tests to see if it is zero. So as Peter Cordes points out, perhaps a better way of thinking of it is whether `cx` can ever be 1. The `SHL` instruction ensures that this will never be the case, as the result of `cx` after the `SHL` is either 0 (in which case `LOOP` will decrement it to -1 and thus continue looping), or >= 2 (in which case `LOOP` will decrement it to >= 1 and thus continue looping).

Comment: *`cx` will never be 0*... **after** LOOP executes.  That's an important distinction that can lead to newbie confusion.  Unlike the `rep` prefix, `loop` only checks [E|R]CX after the decrement, so it implements the bottom of `do{}while(--cx)`.  So the thing to look for is whether CX can ever be `1` when the code reaches the LOOP instruction.  (And it's pretty easy to see that `shl`'s result is either 0 or >= 2.)

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. I wrote the last explanation in a bit of a hurry (I'd initially forgotten part 2 of the question), and it didn't even occur to me that it might be unclear. I've added a further clarification. I think a lot of what leads to newbie confusion is just the `loop` instruction itself. CISC instructions are much more difficult to reason about, and since it's only used in certain rare situations where you are optimizing for minimal code size, I don't know why you would be teaching it at all. `dec`+`jnz` is much easier to understand because it's all written explicitly!

Comment: Totally agree that LOOP is just extra complexity for beginners.  If people want to get students started with a looping idiom before explaining exactly how it works, `dec/jnz` is just as good.  It makes more sense to me to just not even mention LOOP, XLAT, or any of the weird stuff.